# Unity LookAt function. Only looking at 'Root' of object, even if set to look at child transform

Tags: unity, c#

I made a small routine to make the camera zoom in to the players face when they finish a level.

It mostly worked, until I tried to make it focus on the players head rather than feet. This time I did read the Unity docs for `Transform.LookAt` but it just says it will point at the `target`.

My player object has its root on the floor. But one of the child objects is `sunglasses` which I would like the camera to `LookAt`.

How I've done this is created a script called `SunGlasses` (purely to add it as a Component on the `Sunglasses` object). Then in my code (below) I find use `GetComponentInChildren` to find the sunglasses of the player and look at that instead. However it still aims at the player's feet.

```
switch (camMode)
        {
            case CAM_MODE.FOLLOW:
                transform.localEulerAngles = camera_eulers;
                transform.position = player.transform.position + camera_position_offset;
                break;
            case CAM_MODE.CELEBRATION:
                Transform sunglasses = player.GetComponentInChildren<SunGlasses>().transform;
                transform.LookAt(sunglasses);
                if (transform.position.y > sunglasses.position.y)
                    transform.Translate(0, -zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.Self);
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, sunglasses.position) > MIN_CELEBRATION_DISTANCE)
                    transform.Translate(transform.TransformDirection(transform.forward) * zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                break;
        }
```

So, the result/problem is that it zooms in to his feet, no matter if I use `player.transform` or `sunglasses` as the argument in my `LookAt` function call.

Comment: Can you select the sunglasses object in the Scene view, put the gizmo toggles in "Pivot, Local" mode, and show us a screenshot of where the transform gizmo appears on your character? Make sure you include the tool bar so we can verify the toggles.

Comment: You sir are a genius! I love this website and YOU! The pivot for my sunglasses is also on the floor. It was my mistake whilst modelling

Comment: When formatting your posts, instead of using single quotes around method names, classes, variables & other short code related things, consider using the backtick mark `

Comment: Ah thanks Pikalek, I didn't realise I could do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution to this (after I spent too much time trying to change my code!). The problem was actually where the pivot to my sunglasses model was located (which is defined during the modelling process in Maya in my case).

The pivot for the sunglasses was on the floor at 0,0,0. This was an error on my part.

To fix, I could have gone into Maya and changed it, reexported the model etc. But actually for my specific scenario, I can just use this same technique with the 'head' object in the players rig.

Thank you to the site admin who is super helpful. A credit to Stack Exchange.